# In what order are Jest tests running?

Tags: jestjs

I am having some problems with the order used by Jest to run tests.

Let's imagine that I have two tests:

- `module1.spec.ts`
- `module2.spec.ts`

Each of those modules use a common database. At the beginning of each file, I have a `beforeEach` call that drops the database and recreates fresh data.

If I launch `module1.spec.ts`, everything works fine. If I launch `module2.spec.ts`, everything works fine.

When I try to use the `jest` global command to launch all of my tests, it does not work.

My theory is that `module1.spec.ts` and `module2.spec.ts` are running in a different thread or at least are run kind of "at the same time".

The problem with that approach is that the two tests have to run one after the other because `module1.spec.ts` and `module2.spec.ts` are both dropping the database and creating data during their test.

**Is it something I am missing concerning testing an application with a database?**

**Is their a Jest option to run the tests one after the other?**

Comment: I just found out the `--runInBand` option that does the trick. However, the documentation states "This can be useful for debugging.`. Using this option makes me therefore feel like it's not the right thing to do, that real programmers should use something else... Am I doomed to mock all of my ORM repositories in order to really make all the tests independents? Is that what real people do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encounterd this problem. By now my method is to `export` the test cases in `module1.spec.js` and `module2.spec.js`, and `require` them in a third file like `index.spec.js`, and custom the test cases running order in `index.spec.js`. I don't use `--runInBand` because I want other test files run parallelly with `index.spec.js`.